# Switching from submit form to remove form using Ajax in Rails 3 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Using an `<% if/else/elsif/end %>` statement, I detect whether an object exists in a User's profile in my Rails 3 app. Depending on the object's existence, I render one of two forms:

- If the object exists, the form that is rendered is associated with the Controller's `remove_object`. It is styled to look like a depressed button, and its submit value is `"-"`.
- If it doesn't, the form that is rendered is associated with the Controller's `create_object`. It is styled to look like a normal button, but its submit value is `"+"`.

I style the forms differently to make the object's existence clear to the user. While the `<% if/else/elsif/end %>` statement works great, I'd like to avoid refreshing the page to change which form is rendered. I have Ajax working on the forms themselves, but am not sure how to change the styling using `.ajaxSuccess` or some other jQuery method.

Here's an `<% if/else/elsif/end %>` statement I use:

```
<% if current_user.profile.higher_ed == @user.profile.higher_ed %>
...
<% end %>
<% elsif current_user.profile.lists.exists?(:category => 'academic', :name => @user.profile.higher_ed) %>
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => "profiles", :action => "remove_academic", :method => :delete), :id =>'remove_form', :remote => true do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :name, @user.profile.higher_ed %>
  <%= submit_tag "-", :class => 'button gray' %>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => "profiles", :action => "create_academic"), :id => "add_form", :remote => true do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :name, @user.profile.higher_ed %>
  <%= submit_tag "+", :class => 'button white' %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I'd like to do is, if the `<% if/else/elsif/end %>` statement shows `add_form`, once the `create_academic` action is finished, `add_form` is replaced with `remove_form`. And vice versa if the `<% if/else/elsif/end %>` statement shows `remove_form`. Is this possible? I'm not sure if my `<% if/else/elsif/end %>` statement will cause problems here or not.

**UPDATE:** Here is my `create_academic.js.erb`:

```
$('ul#goalsEdu').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@goal)) %>");
```

Here's the jQuery I was working with:

```
$(function(){
   $("form#add_goal").show()
   .ajaxStart(function(){
       $(this).show();
   })
   .ajaxStop(function(){
       $(this).replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'profiles/_remove_major_form')");
   })
});
```

So I just have to incorporate that into the `create_academic.js.erb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is with unobtrusive javascript.

Set up your create_academic and remove_academic action to respond_to js (it should already do that since you are using ajax). Now create a remove_academic.js and a create_academic.js file in the views folder for your profiles controller.

This js file will get called whenever ajax is sent to those actions. So all you need to do is select with jquery the form_tag you want to change and render the opposite form from what it was before.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question with my existing `create_academic.js.erb` file.

Comment: Yes you just have to incorporate that into your js file. You might dynamically add an id to the form you are submitting so you know which one to change with create_academic.js.erb